# Why is my Line Chart inverted?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm currently working on a NVD3 line chart with ZoomData.
**I don't understand why my graph is inverted.**

X axis : dates,
Y axis : numbers

Here is a JS Fiddle for you too see what i'm doing : http://jsfiddle.net/A2GK4/

My line chart looks like this : http://hpics.li/d066e46

I put my code here as well.

```
    var svg = d3.select(controller.element).append("svg")

.attr("width", "100%")
.attr("height", "100%");
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
var chart;



nv.addGraph(function() {
    CreateLabels();
  chart = nv.models.lineChart()
  .options({
    margin: {left: 50, bottom: 50},
 // x: function(d,i) { return i},
    showXAxis: true,
    showYAxis: true,
    transitionDuration: 250
  });

   // chart.width(1500)  ;
   // chart.height(720) ;

  chart.xScale = d3.time.scale();


  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")(new Date(d)); });
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

  chart.x( function(d){ return new Date(d.group);} );
  chart.y(function(d){return d.current.count});

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
 return chart;
});




function CreateLabels()
{
    var attributeLabel = controller.createAxisLabel({
        type: 'attribute',
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        position: 'bottom',
        'popover-title': 'Group'
    });

    var metricLabel = controller.createAxisLabel({
        type: 'metric',
        orientation: 'vertical',
        position: 'left',
        'popover-title': 'Bar Height'
    });
}

controller.update = function(data)
{
    var newData = [{key:"Test Line", values: data }];

    d3.select(controller.element).select("svg")
    .datum(newData)
    .call(chart)
    ;

}
```

Thanks for the support !

Comment: Please post an example that runs and shows your issue in JsFiddle.

Comment: You can't see the whole thing running on JS Fiddle since it requires ZoomData. That is why i posted code and an image showing the exact issue.

Comment: Why does your problem require ZoomData? It seems to be a pure d3 issue. When asking a question on StackOverflow, it's good to narrow your code to the exact minimum to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It requires ZoomData API since it handles data parsing itself (via the controller.update as you can see). Nothing will be displayed outside of ZoomData since i select any data file directly from a list, inside the software. I just want to know if i missed any NVD3 parameter to prevent my chart to rotate like this.

Comment: Then start with the data you expect to get from zoomdata. Then you will see if your error comes from d3,or zoomdata. Btw, to me you invested the x and y data.